# I am importing images as textures, and they are getting stretched to form a square

Tags: texturing

I am designing a MacBook Pro, and I have imported the texture for the Touch Bar, and it is getting stretched to form a square.

It is meant to be a thin Touch Bar at the top of the keyboard, however almost all of it is getting cut off due to the stretching.

This is what its meant to look like:
[image]

This is what it looks like in the preview:
[image]

Many thanks in advance.

[edit] This is what it looks like on the object:
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Make sure you have your model UV unwrapped and the UV map connected.

Comment: Don't pay attention to the preview window. It uses a square, so if the image is not square it will display deformed, what does it look like when you use it on the material is what matters. Show an image of what you get on your object.

Comment: @susu I get the exact same, stretched result when I use the preview window, however it gest cut of when the touch bar ends. I shall attach a picture of what it looks like however.

Comment: Did you UV unwrap the object?